# Proving lines of symmetry of circle

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

**Claim.** ***(1)** Every line through the origin is a line of symmetry of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$. And, **(2)** no other line is.*

---

I was able to write a very long and tedious proof of the above claim. Sketch of my proof:

Let $S=(s,\pm \sqrt{1-s^2})$ be an arbitrary point on the circle.

**(1)** Use the Formula below to find the reflection of $S$ in the line $y=mx$ or $x=0$, then verify that this reflection is on the circle.

**(2)** Use the Formula below to find the reflection of $S$ in the line $y=mx+d$ or $x=d$ (where $d\neq 0$), then verify that this reflection is not on the circle (or if it is, then pick another point $T$ on the circle, then verify that the reflection of $T$ in the line is not on the circle).

---

I was wondering if there was another proof that is more elegant/cleverer/shorter.

---

Formula. The reflection of the point $(p, q)$ in the line $ax + by + c = 0$:

$$(p-2a\frac{ap+bq+c}{a^{2}+b^{2}},q-2b\frac{ap+bq+c}{a^{2}+b^{2}}).$$

Comment: Some ideas you can use: 1/ The line of symmetry is the set of all fixed points. 2/ The center is the unique point that is distance 1 from all points on the circle, hence it is fixed. 3/ Thus, the only lines of symmetry pass through the origin.

Comment: Here's a way to shorten it: prove that the norm of a reflected point is guaranteed to be 1 if and only if the line of reflection is through the origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An old geometric proof is shorter. This is the kind of proofs we used to do at school when I was 12.

Let $A$ be a point on circle $C$. Let $L$ be a line of symmetry of $C$. Let $B$ be the symmetrical of $A$ by $L$.

Then segment $AB$ is orthogonal to $L$, and distance from $A$ to $L$ equals distance from $B$ to $L$.
This implies $L$ is the perpendicular bisector of segment $AB$.

The perpendicular bisector of a segment $AB$ is the set of all points at equal distance from $A$ and $B$. The circle center is at equal distance from $A$ and $B$, so it belongs to $L$.

Comment: Similar Q: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828467 please help if you can thanks!

Comment: @user182601 I read Soham Sahan's answer to that question, and it seemed OK to me. I would have made a similar answer, except using the ellipse's foci instead of its axes. In any case I could not find anything better.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful facts about polar coordinates, one can use for this problem:

1. Introduce polar coordinates $x = r\cos(\theta)$, $y = r\sin(\theta)$.
2. A unit circle ($x^{2} + y^{2} = 1$) in polar coordinates are just all points with $r = 1$.
3. The equation for a straight line $ax + by = 0$ through origin is essentially $\tan(\theta) = const$ in polar coordinates as $a\cos(\theta) + b\sin(\theta) = 0$ (this place should be proceeded more accurately), however basically it means that a straight line through the origin is just given by a fixed angle $\theta_{0} = \arctan(—a/b)$ between ($x$-axis and a line itself).
4. The reflection of a point $(r,\theta)$ in a line through origin with the tilt angle $\theta_{0}$ is $(r,2\theta_{0} - \theta)$. Note that this reflexion maps a circle $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ onto itself $(\cos(2\theta_{0}-\theta),\cos(2\theta_{0} - \theta))$. This map is also one to one.

Answer (score 0):

The center of the circle is $O$. A line $XOY$ contains the center of the circle i.e. it's a diameter = $D$
The line $XOY$ is the line of reflection symmetry = $S$
You want to prove $\neg D \implies \neg S$.

You can do this by proving $S \implies D$

Symmetry $\implies$ Same area for both halves.

Area for one half, $A_1 = \frac{\theta_1}{360} \times \pi r^2$

Area for the other half, $A_2 = \frac{\theta_2}{360} \times \pi r^2$

Since $A_1 = A_2$, we see that $\theta_1 = \theta_2 = 180$ degrees.

In other words, $XO = OY = r$ and $\theta_1 = \theta_2 = \angle XOY = 180$ degrees.

That is to say, $XOY$ is the diamter.

We have proved $S \implies D$, which is the same as proving $\neg D \implies \neg S$

Comment: I don't understand what you're proving. Are you just proving that the circle is symmetric in the $y$-axis? I want to prove that if a line does not contain the origin $O$, then the circle is not symmetric in that line.

Comment: I edited my answer, sorry for having missed the point. @user182601