# Ellipse $\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=1$ has no lines of symmetry other than $y=0$ and $x=0$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

Let $a,b>0$ with $a\neq b$. Consider the ellipse $\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=1$.

**Claim.** *This ellipse is symmetric in **(1)** $y=0$ and $x=0$, but **(2)** not any other line.*

---

I was able to write a very long and tedious proof of the above claim. Sketch of my proof:

Let $S=(s,\pm \frac{b}{a} \sqrt{a^2-s^2})$ be an arbitrary point on the ellipse.

**(1)** Use the Formula below to find the reflection of $S$ in $y=0$ or $x=0$, then verify that this reflection is on the ellipse.

**(2)** Use the Formula below to find the reflection of $S$ in any other line, then verify that this reflection is not on the ellipse (or if it is, then pick another point $T$ on the ellipse, then verify that the reflection of $T$ in the line is not on the ellipse).

((1) was easier, (2) was harder/more tedious and what I'm asking about here)

---

I was wondering if there was another proof that is more elegant/cleverer/shorter.

---

Formula. The reflection of the point $(p, q)$ in the line $ax + by + c = 0$:

$$(p-2a\frac{ap+bq+c}{a^{2}+b^{2}},q-2b\frac{ap+bq+c}{a^{2}+b^{2}}).$$

Related: [Proving lines of symmetry of circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4811260)

Comment: An ellipse is to a circle what a rectangle is to a square. The rectangle only has $2$ lines of symmetry. Ergo, drum roll please, an ellipse only has $2$ lines of symmetry

Comment: Take a test line that is *not* the major/minor ellipse. Find a point ($A$) on the ellipse. Find the reflection of $A$ on the test line, call it $B$. If $B$ is *not* on the ellipse, we've proved that no line other than the major and minor ellipse is a line of symmetry for an ellipse.

Comment: @AgentSmith isn't that what exactly the OP said (s)he'd done?

Comment: I hope he doesn't mind, I'm not a 100% lately. Apologies, if it ticks people off.

Comment: Two ellipses are the same only if they have the same foci. Show that there are only two lines leaving foci invariant under reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is a line $L$ which acts as a line of symmetry for a non-circular ellipse $E$. Now reflecting $E$ about $L$ gives us another ellipse $E'$ of exactly the same dimensions, but possibly different orientation and centring. Now for $E'$ to be superimposed over $E$ in the graph, it should have the same major, minor axis and center as $E$. Now consider 2 cases:

- **If $L$ is not through origin**: After reflection of $E$ about $L$, it's center will shift from origin, so $E'$ doesn't have its center at the origin. This is contradictory to the claim of them being superimposed.
- **If $L$ is neither vertical nor horizontal, but passes through origin**:
  The major axis of $E$ was horizontal, after flipping about $L$, it will no longer remain so. So the major axis of $E'$ can't be the major axis of $E$. This is contradictory to the original claim.

So the only case left is $L$ is through origin and it is either horizontal or vertical.This corresponds to $y=0$ and $x=0$.

Comment: You seem to assume that the reflection of the ellipse in a line is also an ellipse. (Which seems "obvious" but isn't that something we have to prove?) // In the first bullet point, you assume that the ellipse has something called the "center" (and this center is unique) and the reflection will also have such a "center". // Similarly with the second bullet point with the "major axis".

Comment: In the second bullet point, say we replace "major axis" with "$x=0$". Then the argument seems to go like this: After reflecting $x=0$ in $L$, we get a non-horizontal line $M$ that isn't $y=0$. So, $M$ which is a line of symmetry of $E^{\prime}$ can't be a line of symmetry for $E$. -- But isn't this ("can't be a line of symmetry for $E$") assuming exactly what we wanted to prove?

Comment: @user182601 point-to-point distances are invariant under reflections, right? So reflecting an ellipse about a line will maintain the focal sum property, thereby proving it to be an ellipse. Also length of major and minor axis will remain constant by the same argument. So its dimensions also remain the same.

Comment: My second point is to say that reflection of $x=0$ about $L$ will result in a line which is not $x=0$. Can you see why this is by using the slope of $x=0$ and an arbitrary slope for $L$ to find the slope of the mirrored line?

Comment: Do you need a proof for invariance of distance under reflection?

Comment: *My second point is to say that reflection of x=0 about L will result in a line which is not x=0.* Yes and what the point of my second comment above was this: Now you are assuming that this line cannot be a line of symmetry for $E$. But that was what was to be proven.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150356/discussion-between-soham-saha-and-user182601).